# How can I fetch User with regular expression?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

For example, a user inputs `@John_Smith hi, what's up!?`
I'd like to call John_Smith's object and deliver notification to him to let him notice.
How can I archive that?

```
username = @comment ??????(I have no idea how to code it here)
@user = User.find_by_username(username)
current_user.send_message(@user, body, subject)
```

The way of judgement is `@username(one space)`

Comment: Will the `@username` only appear at the start of the input? Or can it appear anywhere? If it can appear anywhere, how do you discern whether or not the substring is referring to a username, or something else (like an email)?

Comment: @zeantsoi Yes it only appears at the start of the input line. Just like twitter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
username = @comment.scan(/(?<=^@)\w+(?=[\s|~])/).first
```

console testing:

```
2.0.0-p195 :001 > s = "@John_Smith~hi"
 => "@John_Smith~hi"
2.0.0-p195 :002 > s.scan(/(?<=^@)\w+(?=[\s|_])/).first
 => "John_Smith"
```

Edit: Now accepting `~` or whitespace as separator.

Comment: Thanks does it work when a user input `@John_Smith hello, what's up?` Does it still call @John_Smith's object?

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood what you said about the underscore. Let me update my answer.

Comment: Please ignore about underscore now. I just want it how it is on twitter's reply:)

Comment: Check the console testing, please, and tell me if that's what you need.

Comment: Thanks so much:) one more thing, it should be fetched when it's "@John_Smith hi",too. here it's a space instead of `~`  is it possible to cover both `(space)` and `~` together at the same time?

Comment: Sure, I'm covering both. Give it a try and you'll see.

Comment: I'm trying it now. Is it possible to check the returned result in production log? I want to see result of `target_user = params[:comment][:body].scan(/(?<=^@)\w+(?=[\s|~])/).first` in production.log

Comment: Then we'll be discussing how to debug Rails apps. In this case, you could be using the logger. I personally use the pry gem. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html

Answer (score 1):

to match anywhere in the string:

```
s.scan(/\@(\w+)/).flatten.first
```

Sample:

```
>> s
"Hello @Jhon!"

>> s.scan(/\@(\w+)/).flatten.first
"Jhon"

>> s = "@John_Smith hi, what's up!?"
"@John_Smith hi, what's up!?"

>> s.scan(/\@(\w+)/).flatten.first
"John_Smith"
```

you may like this http://www.rubular.com to have more knowledge about ruby regex